# postfix modify subject based on sender

Tags: postfix, filter

There is a map:

```
email1@example.com ONE
email2@example.com TWO
email3@example.com THREE
```

How to change subject in mails sent to test@example.net this way:
(from email1@example.com, original subject SUBJECT, new subject [ONE] SUBJECT),
(form email2@example.com, original subject Blabla blabla, new subject [TWO] Blabla blabla )

example.net is local domain for postfix server.

Idea is: I'll write content-filter which will change subject and deliver mail with dovecot-lda.
In postfix access tables there is FILTER transport:nexthop

Now I have:
/etc/postfix/header_checks:

```
/^To: email@domain.tld/      FILTER transport:nexthop
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
filter unix -        n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=Rq user=nobody null_sender=
    argv=/home/filter/filter.py ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Questions are: what to add to header_checks and master.cf to make this filter work? I want this filter only for this given email. For other emails is already amavis configured.

Answer (score 0):

FILTER filter:
in header_checks